# Iterating over payload using special expression and construct dynamic input parameters for sql query

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in our project.My payload is as given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<checkClaimSources>
   <claimsCopy>
      <ClmNum>07-111315-001-001</ClmNum>
      <AltClaim />
   </claimsCopy>
   <claimsCopy>
      <ClmNum>07-111315-001-002</ClmNum>
      <AltClaim>test</AltClaim>
   </claimsCopy>
</checkClaimSources>
```

I want to use `int-jdbc:outbound-gateway` to execute a select query where I have to provide all the `<ClmNum>` and `<AltClaim>` values as input parameters to the sql query. The number of `<ClmNum>` and `<AltClaim>` are dynamic here. Is there any way to iterate over all of those and pass them to the query?

Comment: Show, please, what you have tried so far. JDBC Outbound Gateway is based on the `updateSql`. How would like to see that `UPDATE` or `INSERT` with several multi-value params. Do you really think it is possible with a single sql expression?

Comment: Maybe this is a culprit: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3364 ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan, Thanks for the response. I have prepared some raw code using service activator. I was just curious to know whether it can be handled through any spring expression. It appears that there is some limitation as per your latest comment. Thanks much for clearing the things.